# Printing Object doesnt contain all keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, mongoose

Im completely lost. This is some test code I use to print a specific key of an object, then im printing the entire object.

```
console.log(docs[0].mc_ign);
console.log(docs[0]);
```

Now this is the output I see on the console:

```
The__TxT
{
  id: 0,
  status: 1,
  testing: false,
  _id: 5dbc17eb20b3a8594d569570,
  timestamp: 2019-11-01T11:32:59.380Z,
  mc_uuid: 'dac89e44d1024f3b810478ed62d209a1',
  discord_id: '653029505457586176',
  email_address: 'gut97930@eveav.com',
  country: 'Germany',
  birth_month: 3,
  birth_year: 1943,
  about_me: 'about me text',
  motivation: 'motivation text',
  build_images: '',
  publish_about_me: true,
  publish_age: false,
  publish_country: true,
  __v: 0
}
```

Where is the `mc_ign` key?

The object itself comes from mongoose, the missing key is added by me after the fact:

```
docs[i].mc_ign = mc_ign;
```

I tried logging the entire object before and after I add the key and assign the value. They are both the same.
What am I missing? Why can I read the value out, but cant see it?

Comment: Maybe not the issue, but important to note: Browsers like chrome do live updates of an object so at the moment you dump it, the value may be there, but then later it changes. To get a true snapshot of the object at that moment, use `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(docs[0])));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mongoose document object. To achieve what you want do the following.

```
docs[0] = docs[0].toObject();
docs[0].mc_ign = "stuff";
console.log(docs[0])
```

`.toObject()` convert it to plain JS object.